# Is it possible to sort the results of a SELECT query in 2 different ways based on a conditional?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by, mysql-error-1064

The following is invalid syntax but it is what I'm trying to say essentially:

```
  SELECT *  
    FROM categories 
ORDER BY menu_order ASC WHERE parent = '1' || IF parent = '0' ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Is it possible to order the results of a select query differently based on a conditional within the query?

Just in case I wasn't clear, I am trying to order the categories with a parent by menu order and those without a parent by id.

### EDIT

So here's how the database looks like:

```
id | name    | parent | menu_order

==================================

1  | Apparel | 0      | 2
2  | Sports  | 0      | 4
3  | Hats    | 1      | 5
4  | Weights | 1      | 3
5  | Lights  | 0      | 1
```

The result set of the query should be:

```
Apparel
Sports
Lights

Weights
Hats
```

Comment: ...and do the categories with a parent come before the categories without one or after...or what does the overall sort order look like?

Comment: @Gerrat it's all mixed together in the database since the user has the ability to change category order at any time, so cat1 may not have any parents but cats 2 and 3 may and cat 4 may not, etc.

Comment: You can only order by one column at a time.  Assuming the columns are the same data type, you'd have to use a UNION (combining the two columns into a single summary of values from both) to order things.

Comment: So are we only grabbing 1 "cat" at a time?  If not, suppose cat1 has parents, and cat2 doesn't.  We know how to order *within* cat1 and cat2, but does all of cat1 come before cat2, or how is overall order decided?   It may help if you could give a small example of what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use case in the order by, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM categories
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN parent = '1'
    THEN menu_order
    ELSE id
END;
```

Comment: the actual sort takes the bulk of the resources, I don't see any problem with performance, etc; also the question is not mentioning anything about millions of records; if in fact the performance is an issue, consider changing the parent value to be of type bit

Comment: this worked. As for the number of records they will be very minimum since this is a categories table for a website, not a posts or products table. In this situation would this query be performance heavy?

Comment: no problem with performance, just remember that since the sort is dynamic based on the case you will not be able to make it fast with index for example; you might see some issues when you have 100's of thousands of records, which is not in your case

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your data to

```
insert categories values (1 , 'Apparel ', 0 , 1)
insert categories values (2 , 'Sports  ', 0 , 5)
insert categories values (3 , 'Hats    ', 1 , 3)
insert categories values (4 , 'Weights ', 1 , 4)
insert categories values (5 , 'Lights  ', 0 , 2)
```

The output `using the accepted solution` comes out as

```
1   Apparel     0   1
2   Sports      0   5
3   Hats        1   3
4   Weights     1   4
5   Lights      0   2
```

Is that what you are after?  What Gerrat is trying to ask is, is this what you are after?

```
1   Apparel     0   1
2   Sports      0   5
5   Lights      0   2
-------------------------------- << line for emphasis
3   Hats        1   3
4   Weights     1   4
```

i.e. all the unparented ones, before all the parented ones, which is produced by the query below

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
ORDER BY parent,
    CASE
    WHEN parent = '1'
    THEN menu_order
    ELSE id
END;
```

Comment: ...that's exactly why I was asking for an example and overall order.  I woke up this morning, and realized that *SOMEONE IS WRONG ON THE INTERNET* (http://xkcd.com/386/); so had to find this question and comment.  Thanks.  I feel much better now :)  [as an aside, I'm not sure if the following syntax is even valid, but wouldn't it be: `CASE WHEN parent = '1' THEN menu_order ASC ELSE id DESC END;` ...to get the order that OP gave ... or if that's invalid, then this would work: `CASE WHEN parent='1' THEN menu_order ELSE -id END;` (note: `-id`)]

Comment: The question output (menu_order desc) does not match the question pseudo (menu_order ASC), so not sure. To achieve the question output, it would be `case when parent='1' then -menu_order else id end ASC`

Answer (score 0):

The way I've handled this type of feature request is to have that part of the query built on demand. I'm not sure what your program logic looks like, so it's hard to say specifically. Using ibatis, for example, one could choose which clause to include based upon a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your select clause could define a custom 'order_by' field, and you could order by that.